# Replacing find_pos?

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

using Python Jupyter notebook 3.5.1. Got this from somebody who left

```
plan={} 
for client, rank in score.items(): 
    pos = score.find_pos(rank)     
    plan[client]=pos
```

Score is Python dictionary that has entries of client and rank. The purpose is to get index positions. Python throws this error 'dict' object has no attribute 'find_pos'

I searched stackoverflow here and saw many examples involving find_ops. So first a bit odd find_pos is not attribute. Maybe my syntax is off? Or if it is truly no longer working, how to find index values for rank and assign it to variable pos?

Comment: Dictionaries are supposed to be unordered by default. So having the index does not make sense. Why are you trying to extract the index? Also, there is no find_pos method as far as I know.

Comment: There is no such method as `find_pos` in Python built-in libraries. Also note that there is also no such thing as a "position" of an item in a dictionary in Python versions before 3.7 as dictionaries are not ordered. For Python >= 3.7 you may try `list(score.values()).index(rank)`.

Comment: A search on `[python] find_pos` turns up a scattering of SO questions/answers, but all look like user defined functions.  `def find_pos(...):`.  None refer to a builtin method, especially not for a dictionary.  I don't know what you mean by 'index values for rank'.  In the `score` dictionary, `client` is a key, `rank` is its value.

Comment: What's the type (class) of `score`.  The use `items` suggests it is a dictionary. But the `find_pos` method suggests a custom class, possibly a subclass of dict.

Comment: hpaulj, you are right. After spending ~12 hours since this posting, I finally found there is a function call that specifically altered the input requirement. Due to credential block during the job transition, i was not aware I was not reading that subdirectory until ~an hour ago. I just lifted that custom function to the master code  let it run right before it. The error disappeared.